# Как поднять страницу выше перехода по якорной ссылке?

Tags: html, css, ссылки

На сайте есть ссылка `<a href="ссылка#якорь">`, которая переносит человека на другую страницу с якорем. все бы хорошо, но на сайте есть верхнее липнущее меню, которое перекрывает заголовок и к которому переходит пользователь по якорю.
Есть ли возможность сделать так, чтобы заголовок не перекрывался без добавления доп блоков `html` и без скриптов?
не отрабатывает, т.к. здесь переход на другую страницу

Comment: @MasterAlex не дубликат, т.к. в данному случае задуман переход на другую страницу и предлагаемая вами технология не подходит

Comment: @Вася, другая страница тоже твоя?

Comment: а что там сложного ? если надо заякорить блок находяшийся в main.html   id="post" то ссылка такая и будет a href="main.html #post"

Comment: @LenovoID а вы условие задания читали - разве я спрашиваю как заякорить ссылку? меня интересует сдвиг и и для моего случая решение по ссылке выше не подходит

Comment: @Вася, подходит если добавить скрипт из ответа на страницу на которую переходишь

Comment: вот использование якоря до новой страницы смотри волшебство :http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/OXxZEJ?editors=110

Comment: @masteralex Этот вопрос НЕ дубликат. Вопрос по ссылке направлен на улучшение скрипта, прокручивающего страницу.  А этот вопрос касается перехода по ссылке, и у него есть решение вообще без скриптов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вытащить заголовок из-под зафиксированной панели с помощью большого `padding-top` и отрицательного `margin-top`. Внешне заголовок будет неподалёку от предшествующего текста, а расстояние до якоря окажется большим.

Приведённый ниже пример кода гуляет по одной и той же странице, но:

1. сработает и при переходе с другой страницы;
2. не использует скрипты, только CSS.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

h2 {
  margin-top: -50px;
  padding-top: 70px;
}
h2:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav > li:first-child  > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#one">Header 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#two">Header 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#three">Header 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h2 id="one">Header 1</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> 

  <h2 id="two">Header 2</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> 

  <h2 id="three">Header 3</h2>
  <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> <p>Paragraph.</p> 
</div>
```