# Как подстроить прокрутку к якорю

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

На сайте фиксированное меню которое перекрывает часть контента,
прокрутка отлично работает но как подогнать на `-100px` вот скрипт -

```
  $("#contactyGo").click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
         scrollTop: $($(this).attr("#contacty")).offset().top + "px"
      }, {
         duration: 500,
         easing: "swing"       
      });
      return false;
   });
```

пробовал написать - 100 перед "px" - не помогло. Помогите нубу пожалуйста.

Comment: смените расположение #contacty - или сам якорь переместите в css , посмотрите в css это

Comment: Можно как вариант, но в блоках нет участков выше на столько сколько надо, я бы допилил что нибудь но там минимум 5 пунктов меню будет и  точно придется что-то костылять, я думал есть какое-то решение в плане допиливания самого скрипта, я jquery не давно изучаю, но думаю что данная проблема должна решатся иным путем, без переделки шаблона, а по ссылочке ничего похожего не нашел, куда там смотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Функция `.attr()`](http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=43) возвращает значение атрибута, если указать название атрибута. Ваш код должен возвращать ошибку, проверьте консоль. А пока в коде ошибка, срабатывает, скорее всего, обычная ссылка.
2. Перед `.animate` [добавьте `.stop()`](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Пригодится, когда на странице окажется несколько таких кнопок и пользователь начнёт жать их, не дожидаясь окончания прокрутки.
3. jQuery работает вордпрессе [в режиме noConflict](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_.D0.B2_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5_noConflict), поэтому заверните свой код в

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

});
```

4. Сместить якорь можно без скрипта, [поставив ему большой `padding-top` и отрицательный `margin-top`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/543837/208926). Но у вас уже есть скрипт, так что лучше его и доработать:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
  $("#contactyGo").click(function() {
    $("html, body").stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100
    }, {
      duration: 500,
      easing: "swing"       
    });
    return false;
  });
  
});
```

```html
<a id="contactyGo" href="#contacty">Ссылка</a>

<p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> 

<h2 id="contacty">Контакты</h2>

<p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p> <p>Абзац.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: По поводу css -  вариант работает, но  проблема в том что что блок к которому идет прокрутка и блок над ним имеют  разные цвета и вариант с padding-top и margin-top делает так что контент с верхнего блока вылазит на нижний, не совсем красиво смотрится если честно, а по поводу скрипта - не работает и все, может это бред конечно, но я вставил его в код слайдера в шаблоне, сайт на  wordpress если что, я конечно не думаю что ошибка кроется там, да и прокрутка работает плавно, может ли быть какая-то лажа в том что скрипт лежит вместе с скриптом слайдера на jquery? Скрипт вставил Ваш.

Comment: @ТарасПоточилов Консоль ругается на что-нибудь? Ссылку на сайт покажите.

Comment: http://www.shovanka.com.ua только не смейтесь)) вторую ночь делаю, в меню подключил якорь только на контакты

Comment: @ТарасПоточилов Не вижу код с прокруткой к контактам по клику. Ни в [custom.js](http://www.shovanka.com.ua/wp-content/themes/skt-white/js/custom.js?ver=4.6.1), ни в [hook-custom-script.js](http://www.shovanka.com.ua/wp-content/themes/skt-white/js/hook-custom-script.js?ver=4.6.1). Где его найти? Или проверьте, как его подключили.

Comment: скрипт положил сюда shovanka.com.ua/www/wp-content/themes/skt-white/js/ jquery.nivo.slider.js

Comment: @ТарасПоточилов Переложите код `в custom.js` и заверните в `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   });`. Отредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: Положил код в custom.js (Ваш отредактированный), ничего не дало =(.

Comment: @ТарасПоточилов 1) Исправил у себя все `s` на `y`. 2) Это не влияет на результат, потому что скроллит кто-то другой.Не успеваю разобраться..Попробуйте smooth-scroll отключить и/или `console.log()` в код добавить.

Comment: Да Вы правы, этот файл отключил и все заработало! Спасибо Вам ОГРОМНОЕ! Я уж думал мистика какая-то.

Comment: А не подскажите еще один момент, у меня анимация тоже срабатывает при прокрутке, на компе все норм а на телефоне страница на половину  пустая, контент появляется когда проскролю немного, но блин пустая при загрузке, можно как-то или отключить для телефона или поменять координаты, или вообще отключить тоже вариант,  я пробовал отключить файл animation.css но тогда ничего вообще не появляется из анимированного. Подскажите  в какую сторону копать. Спасибо.

Comment: @ТарасПоточилов Создайте новый вопрос и добавьте туда подробности: код страницы, как и какую анимацию подключили, скриншот с телефона. Так будет понятнее и так ваш вопрос больше людей увидит.

Comment: я уже разобрался, спасибо за ответ